# How can I run samples from openVINO

Tags: openvino

I use openVINO R5 2018.5.445. I successfully installed all the software and dependencies for ubuntu 18.04. The test was successful as well. However, the sample models I am trying to run won't build. I followed the full documentation. Using the following commands:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

(https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-InferEngine > Using Inference Engine Samples).

How should I Build the samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Build samples in custom location/path/directory :

```sh
cd /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk/inference_engine/samples   
mkdir build  
cd build CMAKE ..   
make
```

By default, `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` takes `RELEASE`.

Comment: Is there any way to open the samples in eclipse or any other ide so that we can modify it a bit and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

```
cd /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk/inference_engine/samples
```

And then:

```
sudo ./build_samples.sh
```

I can now run models (in this case pose estimation) using this command:

```
./human_pose_estimation_demo -m /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445/deployment_tools/intel_models/human-pose-estimation-0001/FP32/human-pose-estimation-0001.xml
```

Comment: Is there any way to open the samples in eclipse or any other ide so that we can modify it a bit and rebuild

Comment: @SAndrew not that I know of, you can, however, run the model and get its output, using: `./{executable} -m {model} -r -i {stream}`, maybe you can modife this to get the desired result. Example: `./human_pose_estimation_demo -m /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445/deployment_tools/intel_models/human-pose-estimation-0001/FP32/human-pose-estimation-0001.xml -r -i /dev/video0`

Comment: After running build_samples.sh I don't have a human_pose_estimation_demo file over there.